# Start and stop a request to server when use PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, ajax

I created a function in php which send request to a server at every X seconds. Let's say a watcher. I start that watcher via ajax request from javascript using button. Also a button which stops that watcher.

```
$continue = true;

if(isset($_POST["start"])) {
    global $continue;

    $continue = true;

    checkCredentials();

    while($continue) {
        watch();
        sleep(60);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["stop"])) {
    global $continue;
    checkCredentials();

    $continue = false;
}

    $.ajax({
        url: "watch.php",
        data: { ztop: true },
        type: "post",
        success: function (result) {
            $result.append("<p>" + result.message + "</p>");
        }
    });
```

I want to use a thread to do this in php but I don't know how to do ... I want to stop watch when press on button. But the second `isset` will be executed after 60 seconds... How to stop the watch executed in first `isset` ?

Comment: you need a persistence storage

Comment: Can provide a link how to do that ?

Comment: You can use session to store the $continue state. In a long running script you will need to make use of session_start and session_write_close to circumvent the locking. And its probably better to use websocket

Comment: There is reliable good websocket for php ?

Comment: Something like Ratchet websocket